# Is there a way to make a plugin display lines 'between' numbered lines in atom?

Tags: atom-editor

In the atom editor I'd like to be able to create notes 'in between' the lines of a file. I'm more than happy to do this via a plugin, but I'm wondering if someone more experienced in the API can confirm whether it's even possible before I dive in.

Basically, if I open a file with 10 lines, I want to be able to 'insert' new lines between some of them (which will be saved to another file), while still maintaining the line numbering of the original file. Eg:

```
1 Hello
2 World
.   This is a note line saved in another file 'attached' to line 2
3 Foo
4 Etc
```

Think along the lines of [inline comments on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/commenting-on-differences-between-files/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [block decorations](http://blog.atom.io/2016/02/03/introducing-block-decorations.html) to inject text between two lines:

> A block decoration is a special kind of decoration that allows you to insert a DOM node before or after a certain line, and have it follow the line as the buffer changes. You can see it in action by running the snippet below in the DevTools:

```
var element = document.createElement('div')
element.textContent = 'Block decorations! '
var editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()
var marker = editor.markScreenPosition([0, 0])
editor.decorateMarker(marker, {type: 'block', position: 'before', item: element})
```

[image: Screenshot of Block Decoration]

In your case, you would be injecting text rather than GIFs, but you get the idea!

Comment: Awesome! That is exactly the kind of functionality I was hoping for :3 Thanks!